# I need to create a random number generator in php using mt_rand which should only generate random numbers

Tags: php

I need to create a random number generator in php using `mt_rand` which should only generate random numbers. I know I need to use an infinite loop. How can I achieve this?

This is what I've already tried:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM random";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query); 
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j) {
    $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if($row["randomcol"]==$a) { 
    do {
        echo "\n fetched";
        echo $row["randomcol"];
        echo "\n generated";
        echo $a;
        echo "\n repetition";
        $a=mt_rand(1,10); 
        echo "\n Just after regeneration";
        echo $a; 
    } while ($row["randomcol"]==$a);
 }
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Comment: I want to write my own random number generator. I am using an MySQL db to store generated value

Comment: cool, Show what you have done so far.

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM random";

    $result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
    $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    
 for($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j){
            
            
   
   
   $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   
      
   if($row["randomcol"]==$a)
   {
 
   do {
     echo "\n fetched";
     echo $row["randomcol"];
     echo "\n generated";
     echo $a;
     echo "\n repetition";
     $a=mt_rand(1,10);
     echo "\n Just after regeneration";
     echo $a;
     
    } while ($row["randomcol"]==$a);

   }
   
   
   
    }

Comment: If you have extra information, try to add it to your question (instead of a comment).

Answer (score 0):

Use rand() function.

```
$random_number = rand(1000,99999); //random number between 1000 and 99999
```

Comment: I want the function to throw an infinite error message if it repeats generating.

Comment: To make it unique you can use current timestamp with time() function that will return unix timestamp and it is numeric. And add this with random number like $unique_number = $random_number+time();

Comment: what on earth do you mean by `infinite error message`?

Comment: Thanks a lot Subankar

Comment: @SubhankarMitra …that doesn't make it any more random.

Answer (score 0):

I have created sample random generator function in php. You can change length and characters according to your need.

```
function generateRandomString($length = 10) {
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}
```